# MessageResources msg=getResources() is not supporting for struts2

Tags: java, struts2

```
public class SearchUserAction  extends ActionSupport {
     public String execute(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
          MessageResources messages = getResources(request);
   }
}
```

could please help me i am new to Struts2. i am migrating my project Struts1 to Struts2.

Comment: Struts 2 is completely different than Struts 1. Check out the S2 I18N docs and start from there.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: put `@Override` on the method and try to refactor your method to comply to this annotation